# Which Character should I use to separate some URLs?

Tags: html, url, get, character

I have some URLs, like these:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://example.com/Hello/EveryBody/?page=5
http://another.example.com/GoodBye.html?q=me%20%40%20%3Cstackoverflow%3E%20!%3B
```

I'm getting URLs from user, and I want to put them in one string and send them to C# Server (with jQuery `ajax` method, by `GET` request).

(For example, if I had numbers instead of URLs, I could use `;` for separation of numbers -> `123;234;2012;4;0;99`... But there are URLs now...)

So, what is the best character to separate URLs?

Comment: I don't know... Please note that I URLEncode URLs with javascript `encodeURIComponent`. So, which one is the **best and safest character?**

Comment: Why not encode them, then concate them into a string with `|` between them?

Comment: So, you are saying that `|` is safe?

Comment: The vertical bar will be encoded as `%7C`. It's not a security hazard, and when you send it to your C# code you can regex it out and separate the URIs back into separate strings. Even if it does get encoded, you can still use `%7C` in your regex.

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML I should first encode URLs, and then use `|` to avoid get separator encoded :)

Comment: Can you post your comments as an answer?

Comment: Why not serialize as a JSON array, send that to the server, and have the server deserialize and do whatever it needs? Seems much more fail-safe than using a delimiter character that could potentially be needed in the URL.

Comment: I might add that the JSON approach would require a `POST` to be practical, so that may or may not address your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pipe `|` or [vertical bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) character. `encodeURIcomponent` will encode a vertical bar as `%7C`.

I recommend encoding all your URLs, then concatenating them into one string with vertical bars in between. That way, in your C# code, you can find the vertical bars, then use their positions to regex out the URLs.